# How do I create timestamps in my decoder filter?

Tags: filter, directshow, decoder

Thanks to Roman R's answer to my previous question I now have an asynchronous filter wrapping a 3rd party decoder library.

The encoded input samples are coming from a network source. At present I am not adding timestamps to the decoded frames so the framerate is rather jerky as it is dependent on the time the data packets are received.

When the library decodes a full frame it also provides a UTC timestamp of the time the frame was captured according to the clock on the source encoder.

The question is: how can I related this to the stream time and create a sensible value for the SetTime function? I've played around with it but what ever values I put in just seem to lock up the filter graph at the CBaseOutputPin::Deliver function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest time stamping is as follows. You time stamp your first media sample with a zero (see adjustment note in next paragraph) and the following will be stamped with a difference against it. That is, you start streaming and you obtain first sample from your network source, you remember this time `UTC0` and attach zero to the DirectShow media sample. Following frames 1, 2 ... N with UTC times `UTC1`... `UTCN` and will be converted to DirectShow time `UTCN` - `UTC0`. You might need an additional conversion to proper units, as DirectShow will need 100 ns units and your network source might be giving you something like 1/90000 s.

Since your source is perhaps a live source, and your first frame might be obtained not exactly at graph run time, you might be adjusting resulting media sample time stamp using a difference between current filter graph's `IReferenceClock::GetTime` and time received as argument to `IBaseFilter::Run` call.

Comment: Thanks. I did try something along these lines but I used the current value of IReferenceClock::GetTime without subtracting the time in IBaseFilter::Run. I assume this caused my filter to lock up as the value returned by GetTime is probably the system time rather than the filter time.. is that correct?

Comment: Yes this value is not zero aligned so you probably scheduled your data to be played back after a long delay.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it another go in the morning.